What language are the alsa configuration files (such as ~/.asoundrc) written in?
Here's a brief snippet of an alsa config file (/usr/share/alsa/pcm/default.conf):
pcm.!default {
        @args [ CARD ]
        @args.CARD {
                type string
                default {
                        @func getenv
                        vars [
                                ALSA_PCM_CARD
                                ALSA_CARD
                        ]
                        default {
                                @func refer
                                name defaults.pcm.card
                        }
                }
        }
...

Does this language exist outside of alsa, and if so, what language is it?

This configuration language is specific to ALSA (and has no formal name other than the "ALSA configuration language"). See src/conf.c in alsa-lib.
